# Creating a WIA Device Manager gives a compile time error

Tags: c, winapi, wia

I'm following the sample from msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629848(v=vs.85).aspx:

```
HRESULT CreateWiaDeviceManager(IWiaDevMgr2 **ppWiaDevMgr)
{
CoInitialize(NULL);

// Validate arguments
if (NULL == ppWiaDevMgr)
    return E_INVALIDARG;

// Initialize out variables
*ppWiaDevMgr = NULL;

// Create an instance of the device manager
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_WiaDevMgr2, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWiaDevMgr2, (void**)ppWiaDevMgr ); 

// Return the result of creating the device manager
return hr;
}
```

But in compilation time I get this errors:

Error   389 error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const CLSID' to 'const IID *const '

Error   392 error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const IID' to 'const IID *const '

On the parameters of CoCreateInstance.

I didn't do any meaningful changes from the sample code...
Can anyone suggest why I'm getting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( &CLSID_WiaDevMgr2, NULL, &CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, &IID_IWiaDevMgr2, (void**)ppWiaDevMgr );`

In C++ the code builds as posted on MSVC2013, with includes:

```
#include <guiddef.h>
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <Wia.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```